# Microsoft graph change tracking

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft.Graph library which I got off of Nuget. I have a problem regarding change tracking using deltas. Suppose

I am getting changes to users using something like the code below:

```cs
var usersDeltaRequest = client
    .Users
    .Delta()
    .Request(usersDeltaLink == null ? new Option[0] : new []
    {
        new QueryOption("$deltatoken", usersDeltaLink)
    });

var users = await usersDeltaRequest.GetAsync();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    //code that updates the user goes here
}
```

My problem is that in this case, what gets returned is a `User` object. However since this is a `delta`, not all the fields in the object get populated. Only the ones that have been changed are guaranteed to be populated.

Now were I to parse the `JSON` returned manually, it would be easy to see which fields have actually been included in the response, since only those will be included in the `JSON`.

However, the library returns a `User` object and leaves the fields which haven't been returned as `null`. In this case, it does not seem possible to disambiguate between a field which simply hasn't been returned in the delta vs a field that actually does contain a null value.

Is there something I'm missing in how the library should be used? Because as it stands, it appears as if the library does lose some critical information, because I can't rely on the returned `User` object to reliably update my database, because a changed field containing a `null` value and a field that hasn't changed both result in a `null` value in the returned .Net object.

This obviously also applies to other types of resources, I just chose `Users` for the example.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the API docs at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users it sez:

> The optional $select query parameter is included in the request to
>   demonstrate how query parameters are automatically included in future
>   requests.

I haven't tried this.  Did you include the properties you want to track changes for on your original request?  Or perhaps try `$select=*` to return everything?  The API sez:

> By default, only a limited set of properties are returned
>   (*businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail,
>   mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname,
>   userPrincipalName*).

Comment: Yes I know about the documentation and that part is well documented. I am asking specifically about the Microsoft.Graph .Net library, which is supposed to abstract all the web requests and the json away.

Comment: Specifically the case where a field has changed to a null value. In that case, the library returns a .Net object with that field set to null. However if it hasn't changed, that field is set to null as well. Making it impossible to differentiate between the two cases. This means that one would have to do the request manually (using a .Net WebRequest, for example) and parse the returned json manually in order to be able to handle deltas reliably in all cases, even when this specific case comes up, and therefore can't rely on the library for deltas